# Unable to test buttons in cards in botiumbox community edition

Tags: direct-line-botframework, botium-box

[image]

Hi,

I am testing the chatbot as above bot. When I click on the buttons in the adaptive card the respective text is displayed in the card. But while I'm running that in live chat I'm getting ajax error.

The output data is linked in the json object internally. So should I need to change any advanced settings in botium box community edition to test the bot? In this case, the user will just click on the button, bot will respond by giving the respective adaptive card, the user will not enter any text.

Can we test this type of scenario in the botium box community edition?

buttons taking null value

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: No it is not duplicated in our chatbot. But while testing in botim box live chat I'm getting like above format.

Comment: I'm unable to add the screenshot of the ajax error. When ever I click one of the button the error seems as below "Failed sending to chatbot: Error posting activity:ajax error 400"

Comment: Sorry i wanted to ask for your adaptive card json, not for its schema. Could you send it?

Comment: Without JSON i have two questions: 

Where is "Please select from..." caming from? I suppose from a subcard? (It means we have a bug)

For example if you push "Case Studies" then you got Ajax error? What is the definition of "Case Studies"? (If I test, my buttons are working in LiveChat)

Comment: While I'm running the same in my bot emulator, I'm getting accurate output. But while clicking any of the buttons in live chat I'm getting ajax error in Botiumbox community edition. When we click any of the button we get the respective text in an adaptive card.

Comment: By clicking the button bot will display the adaptive card without taking text from user. This data is linked in code internally in JSON.

Comment: And also can you please check the sample echo bot buttons testing. While testing the sample echo bot buttons in botium box community edition, the bot encountered with null value. Not taking the value of button pressed: First button, instead showing button pressed: null, Thus the test case fails.

Comment: script and screenshot please

Comment: #me
show me buttons

#bot
Here are some buttons
BUTTONS First Button|Second Button
INTENT buttons

#me
BUTTON First Button

#bot
BUTTON PRESSED: First Button

#me
BUTTON Second Button

#bot
BUTTON PRESSED: Second Button
 this is the script

Answer (score 1):

1. Asserting problem should be fixed with the next release. (There will
   be licence changes in next version. Most important is, you have to
   renew it monthly)
2. I suppose you set DIRECTLINE3_BUTTON_TYPE capability to text, but you are sending json as button click. (send text as button click, or set
   [DIRECTLINE3_BUTTON_TYPE](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-directline3#directline3_button_type-and-directline3_button_value_field) capability to "event") Details: It depends on your backend how the
   button clicks are handled. You have to configure Botium
   correspondingly. [See also this
   short article](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/63209497/How+Can+I+Simulate+Buttons+with+my+Azure+Bot)